# VTTCue with indefinite end time

Tags: webvtt

I am creating a text track with VTTCues, indicating titles for what is happening live.  Since the performance is live, the end time isn't known at the time that the cue starts.  I've tried the following:

```
new VTTCue(100, null, 'woot');
```

This doesn't work.  `null` gets cast to `0`.

```
new VTTCue(100, Infinity, 'woot');
```

This throws an error, as Infinity is not a non-finite double.

Once the cue is created, later on I will need to update its end time, and add the next cue.

What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: You're looking for roll-up captions. Looks like W3C is still working out the details, unfortunately. See https://www.w3.org/community/texttracks/wiki/RollupCaptions and more recently https://github.com/w3c/webvtt/issues/318.

Comment: @approxiblue Thanks for the note.  It does seem that RollupCaptions is closer to what I need.  In my case, the presentation of the caption is irrelevant.  I'm provided titles for live music performances, and these performances are audio only.  When a band is live, I expect the person at the encoding laptop to type in the name of the song.  Then some JavaScript on the playing page can get an event for a new cue and display it however it wants.  I can work around this and just use my own events... I was hoping to implement something standards-based.  Anyway, thanks for digging up that info.